# How can I parse a link within locally stored html using python?

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to extract text from a link within an html file that is locally stored. The link is as follows:

```
file:///Users/my_name/Dropbox/folder_name/wisenews/18Jan2021%20(1).html#body.202003310521728.1
```

I can't seem to use `open()` to access this link. I tried the following but does not work.

```
open(file:///Users/my_name/Dropbox/folder_name/wisenews/18Jan2021%20(1).html#body.202003310521728.1)
```

How can I access this link?

I added screenshots of jupyter notebook for more elaboration
[image]

Comment: `file://` is not part of the file path. Have you tried omitting it?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes, Users/.. doesnt work as well

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I use open() and get error message that file cannot be found

Comment: Have you checked that the file exists and its path is the same as what you pass to `open()`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it's not a file but the link in the html. I can open the html with open() but not the link within the html

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the actual file path to the function

Should be something like:

```py
open("C:/Users/Users/my_name/Dropbox/folder_name/wisenews/18Jan2021%20(1).html")
```

Comment: I am trying to access the link in the html, Users/my_name/Dropbox/folder_name/wisenews/18Jan2021%20(1).html#body.202003310521728.1

Comment: Yes, I added a screenshot for more elaboration

Comment: If the notebook is in the same folder as this file maybe try adding ./ before the path